# Mocha silently ignores assertion failures in async code

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocha.js

```
describe('the server', function() {
  let udp;
  afterEach(() => {
    if (udp) {
      udp.close();
      udp = undefined;
    }
  });

  it('should accept a packet and provide an ack', async function(done) {
    await empty_outbound();
    await empty_inbound();

    udp = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    // wait for the ack
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      udp.on('message', async function(msg, rinfo) {
        console.log('msg2', msg);
        console.log('rinfo2', rinfo);
        assert.deepEqual(1, 2);
        
        ...many other checks and assertions...
        
        resolve();
      });
    });
    udp.bind(PORT, ADDR);

    send_a_packet_to_provoke_the_ack();

    return promise;
  });
});
```

In the code above, execution of the test silently stops at `assert.deepEqual(1, 2);` (which I put in to test why other assertion failures were causing a silent stop).

This is probably my failure to understand async, rather than an issue in mocha.

How do I make assertions which fail in async functions cause mocha to report the failed assertion, rather than just running to timeout?

Comment: `udp.on` looks like something that runs after the mocha function has finished.

Comment: @danh Sorry, I've just added a missing promise constructor.

Comment: Okay. Shouldn't you await that promise?

Comment: No, I've figured it out. You can return a Promise from an async test function and Mocha knows what to do with it.  Awaiting the Promise is also fine, but you do need to use a try/catch and call reject() to report the assertion failures.

Answer (score 0):

What I missed was that I have to catch the error(s) thrown in the `Promise`, and call `reject()`.

```
// wait for the ack
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  udp.on('message', async function(msg, rinfo) {
    try {
      console.log('msg2', msg);
      console.log('rinfo2', rinfo);
      assert.deepEqual(1, 2);

      ...many other checks and assertions...
    
      resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
});
```